# Integrating new Paypal iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, paypal

I need to integrate new paypal ios sdk in my app.But my question is that which Paypal solution (e.g. Standard, Express checkout, Payflow etc.) client need to have in order to integrate this SDK?

Thanks in advance